# White gap between header image (slider) and menubar

Tags: html, css

I've created a slider image scroller and a menubar that should slide over when scrolling / and that should adapt when resizing the window.

When I resize, there appears a white 'gap' between my slider and menubar. I'm sure I'm overlooking something silly.

**This is the main css for the navigation bar**

```
#Topnav {

    cursor: default;
    background-color: #dcd9d6;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 150;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px #383433;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

**This is the main css for the slider image**

```
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

However, I have quite a lot of css running in my file, while trying (trial and error) to get it to get responsive. I've included a large part of it in this fiddle, cause I'm suspecting something silly slipped in while messing around.

Also, the white 'gap' is clearly visible in the rendering window.

**Link to the fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/abLtxg9h/1/

The menubar should follow the bottom of the slider image at all times when resizing. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move your nav bar into the same parent div as your slider (header). Then:

```
.nav{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: You only need it to be fixed if you want it there all the time. Otherwise just add it after your slideshow in the same container and it will always be right below

Comment: this doesn't work for me cause then my navbar get's stuck in my header image. This is because I've added some css code to the main & header divs that allows the menubar to scroll over. Together with some javascript it 'clones' and stays sticky on top